# Apache 2.4 CustomLog format: request duration sometimes not logged

Tags: apache, duration

We have an Apache 2.4.9 running at a customer environment (Windows) and wanted to log request duration for certain analysis purposes, so we added the corresponding "%D" format to the custom LogFormat spec we are using.

This is the log format relevant section of the httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" common

<IfModule logio_module>
  # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

CustomLog "E:/XXX/httpd/logs/access.log" common
```

Since logio isn't loaded, and since we are not referring to any custom log format other than the one named "common", I would expect the second LogFormat "common" to be effective for writing to the access.log. Notice the "%D" near the end of the LogFormat line, which should give me the request duration for every request. But actually, the logs we are getting look more like this (IPs and paths slightly obfuscated):

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:32 +0000] "POST /x/y/z/keepAliveSession HTTP/1.1" 200 116
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:34 +0000] "POST /x/y/z/keepAliveSession HTTP/1.1" 200 116
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:34 +0000] "POST /x/y/z/keepAliveSession HTTP/1.1" 200 116
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6646
XXX.XXX.XXX.125 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:37 +0000] "POST /x/y/z/keepAliveSession HTTP/1.1" 200 116 81301
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:38 +0000] "POST /x/y/z/keepAliveSession HTTP/1.1" 200 116
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:40 +0000] "GET /a/b/c/d/des_help.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 3141
XXX.XXX.XXX.26 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:41 +0000] "GET /a/b/c/e/f/index.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 9033
XXX.XXX.XXX.121 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:39 +0000] "POST /u/v/w/x HTTP/1.1" 200 132 2994469
XXX.XXX.XXX.121 - - [21/Dec/2015:13:54:42 +0000] "POST /u/r/s/se/v?mode=LAX HTTP/1.1" 200 4 31273
```

As you can see, some lines show the request duration, while others don't. It seems that this is a bit related to the client (notice, that the requests from the IP ending with 26 have the duration, while the ones ending in 121 or 125 don't). Also notice that the exact same request (but by different clients) sometimes have the duration, sometimes not (see lines 1-3 and 6 vs. line 5).

From other installations we have never seen such a behavior, checking Apache change logs and the bug tracker also didn't turn up anything.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: different customlog/logformat specified in a vhost w/ the same filename?

Comment: I checked all config files (we have the central httpd.conf plus a number of includes) No custom log format without the %D anywhere to be found.

Comment: Actually, the virtual host WAS the hint I needed. I was looking for CustomLog and LogFormat only, the VirtualHost for SSL was using TransferLog, and seemed to have used some default log format.THX!

Comment: Actually, I wonder if it is a good idea to have several CustomLog or TransferLog directives write into the exact same file. If one did something similar in, e.g., log4j, (i.e., multiple appenders writing to the same file), I am pretty sure results would be messy.

Comment: I don't think it's safe in Apache because it would be done via multiple file descriptors and not coordinated.